# Should rough, rustic terracotta tiles be treated with linseed oil? Or what else?

Tags: brick, protection, woodstove, oil, hearth

I have seen advice (for example [here](https://homesteady.com/12501633/how-to-get-oil-out-of-tile) - note, scroll down 1 article) to seal terracotta tiles with one or more coats of boiled linseed oil and then floor wax.

The pictures I've seen attached to this advice use fairly smooth tiles (for example [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FonA7VfIIh8), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEDgmkRTuzg), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaxAUE4wnvQ)) but my tiles are quite rough and rustic as shown below:

[image]

Would linseed oil and floor wax be suitable coatings for such tiles? Are there any additional caveats for tiles such as these? Would an alternative coating be more suitable?

(Note that these will be used to surround a wood burning stove, and although it is highly unlikely that they will be exposed to naked flames, I would like to know that whatever I use will not present a fire hazard e.g. by releasing volatile gases if warmed.)

Comment: These are to be used for the surround only, not inside the firebox, right? Just looking for complete clarity. Also, the sealing process seems to be recommended for floor tile (and I'd think roofing tile, though it's not mentioned). What would be the purpose of sealing these tiles on the wall?

Comment: For the surround, yes. A friend advised me this will a) look nice and b) keep them from shedding or accumulating dust.

Comment: Fair enough! IMHO, oiling the tile would cause the dust to stick _more_, not less, but again, opinion, not experience.